# Bash: Run multiple commands in background, with options

Tags: bash

My understanding is that in Bash you can run multiple commands in the background like so:

```
$ (cmd1; cmd2) &
```

But say I want to pass options to both commands. This creates an issue where an option meant for cmd2 is passed to cmd1 instead.

```
$ (cmd1 --A; cmd2 --b) &
Error: cmd1 has no option "b".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This works as expected for me. Are you doing something else, like trying to store the command in a variable?

Comment: Which commands are cmd1 and cmd2? It looks that the problem are the arguments, not the recipe (cmd1; cmd2) &

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I do not share your observation. I created two shell-scrips, `cmd1` and `cmd2`, with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
for arg in $* ; do
    echo "$0: $arg"
done
```

and did:

```
ljm@ronsard:~/tmp$ (./cmd1 --A; ./cmd2 --b) &
[2] 23984
ljm@ronsard:~/tmp$ ./cmd1: --A
./cmd2: --b

[2]+  Done                    ( ./cmd1 --A; ./cmd2 --b )
```

So, you see that the arguments are passed to the correct command.

The problem is probably in your `cmd2`, which tells you incorrectly that it's name is `cmd1`. Try `cmd2 --b` to verify this.